# Update from multiple databases in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables in two different databases. I'd like to update column *data* in **db1** with column *data* in **db2** based on *id*. db1 contains less rows than db2, so I do not want to copy over the whole table. I only want to update the *data* column of the already existing rows in db1.

I'm using SQLite (and am restricted to using this). Is there a query I can use that does the above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With db1 open, try this:

```
ATTACH 'path/to/db2' AS db2;
UPDATE main.table
SET data = (SELECT data FROM db2.table WHERE main.table.id = db2.table.id)
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM db2.table WHERE main.table.id = db2.table.id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried it out, all the rows in db1get updated with the data from the first matching row in db2. I.e. they all have the same content now..

Comment: I found out the problem: when opening db1 and attaching db2 I have to use 'main' for db1 name. Another solution is attaching both databases and using the "AS .." name. Thanks!